# How do access modifiers internally work in JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, access-modifiers

How  do **access modifiers** internally work in **JVM**?

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/) covers this in detail. In particular, [section 2.7.4 Qualified Names and Access Control](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#18914) states:

> A field, method, or constructor of a class may be declared using at most one of the `public`, `private`, or `protected` keywords. A `public` member may be accessed by any class or interface. A `private` member may be accessed only from within the class that contains its declaration. A member that is not declared `public`, `protected`, or `private` is said to have *default access* and may be accessed from, and only from, anywhere in the package in which it is declared.